# How to use Room in android project

Tags: java, android, android-room

I want use Room into my app and i added this dependencies :

```
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'

google()
```

But when click on run button show me below error message :

```
Could not find compiler.jar (android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/persistence/room/compiler/1.1.1/compiler-1.1.1.jar
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add dependenci in you build.gradle file?

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I write below codes `allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Google Maven repository to your project?
You should add Google's Maven repository in your top-level `build.gradle` file like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

Source:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies

Comment: I write below codes `allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

As stated here
[android.arch.persistence.room](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/package-summary)
The android.arch Architecture Components packages are no longer maintained. They have been superseded by the corresponding androidx.* packages.

*Try this Instead*

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
  annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

as stated here
[Androidx room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room)